# Encoding issue piping value to command

Tags: powershell

I have a head scratcher and I am unsure on how to solve this one. 
I am looking for an enlightened individual that would know what this is about.

Let's begin with the center piece of this interrogation, this simple piece of code.

```
Function New-Thingy {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]$testing
    )
  # Tried playiing with encoding but it didn't do anything.
  #  $Encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default
  #  [Console]::OutputEncoding = $Encoding
  #  [Console]::InputEncoding = $Encoding

      Write-Host $testing
}

'options — test' | New-Thingy
```

*Please note that the problem does not occurs in Powershell ISE but do in VSCODE and Powershell (by invoking the ps1 script containing this code).*

From both VS code and Powershell, running the script gives the following output:
**options â€” test** instead

Output should be : **options — test**

Using **F8** on that line of code afterward produce the correct output but F5 execution always output on the wrong codepage.

Furthermore, using an expandable string instead of single quoted produce the following error message :

```
+ "options â€” test" | New-Thingy
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
```

- How do I get the correct output ?
  I attempted changing the console output / input encoding but it changes nothing
- What is happening with the expandable string and is there any way to prevent it ?

Again, Powershell ISE do the work properly, produce the correct output and does not give any error using expandable string there.

Regular powershell console does and so does VS code.

I am continuing to seek for an answer but I must admin I am a bit lost here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you're using a long-dash (`—`).  In Windows PowerShell, if your script is not saved as utf8 with bom, it parses it as "ANSI" encoding which this character falls outside the range of since it takes up more than 1-byte as you can see by the glyph being misrepresented.  This is corrected in PowerShell Core where the default is utf8 encoding parsing (versus ANSI).

Saving your Windows PowerShell scripts as `utf8bom` going forward will remediate this "bug".

In VSCode `settings.json` with `powershell` extension:

```
"[powershell]": {
    "files.encoding": "utf8bom"
}
```

Comment: Woah ! Double thanks for the VSCode setting !!! That will be very handy.

Comment: @SagePourpre The only place that will cause friction is if you're writing scripts for powershell **core** (which won't be very soon in my experience).